# Python - sort dataframe on two columns not working

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a problem when sorting data based on two columns!

In general I would like to set a timezone on a dataframe with a time change. Unfortunately

```
tz.localize("Europe/Berlin", infer_dst=True)
```

throws an error as the data are not properly sorted (at least I think that is the reason..)

So I tried the sort the following dataframe:

```
index                value   test1                 test2
2015-10-25 02:00:00   10     2015-10-25 02:00:00   0
2015-10-25 02:00:00   20     2015-10-25 02:00:00   1
2015-10-25 02:15:00   30     2015-10-25 02:15:00   0
2015-10-25 02:15:00   40     2015-10-25 02:15:00   1
2015-10-25 02:30:00   60     2015-10-25 02:30:00   0
2015-10-25 02:30:00   70     2015-10-25 02:30:00   1
2015-10-25 02:45:00   80     2015-10-25 02:45:00   0
2015-10-25 02:45:00   90     2015-10-25 02:45:00   1
```

to get the following output

```
index                value   test1                 test2
2015-10-25 01:45:00   5     2015-10-25 01:45:00   0
2015-10-25 02:00:00   10     2015-10-25 02:00:00   0
2015-10-25 02:15:00   30     2015-10-25 02:15:00   0    
2015-10-25 02:30:00   60     2015-10-25 02:30:00   0
2015-10-25 02:45:00   80     2015-10-25 02:45:00   0
2015-10-25 02:00:00   20     2015-10-25 02:00:00   1
2015-10-25 02:15:00   40     2015-10-25 02:15:00   1
2015-10-25 02:30:00   70     2015-10-25 02:30:00   1
2015-10-25 02:45:00   90     2015-10-25 02:45:00   1
2015-10-25 03:00:00   90     2015-10-25 03:00:00   1
```

I tried:

```
df.sort(["test1","test2"],ascending=[1, 1])
```

however, for some reason the order does not change. Any ideas?

Hi, I extended the desired output

Comment: Are you sure? You want separated sort columns `test1` and `test2` and then overwrite dataframe by these sorted column? Then you can use `df['test1'] = df['test1'].sort_values().values` and `df['test2'] = df['test2'].sort_values().values`.

Comment: note overwrite at all. I would like to sort the whole dataframe based on the index (which a copied to the test column) and the column "test2".  Basically, I need the quarters: 02:00-02:45 together

Comment: well, your input dataset is already sorted by test1, test2.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I something missing. Because if I want sort by `test1` - `print df.sort_values(["test1"],ascending=True)` - this unsorted `test2`. And if I sort by `test2` by `print df.sort_values(["test2"],ascending=True)` it is same as `print df.sort_values(["test2","test1"],ascending=[1, 1])` - `test1` is unsorted. I think this is all correct... And sort both columns without overwritten is not posible.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change order of columns and sort by `["test2","test1"]`:

```
>>> df.sort(["test2","test1"],ascending=[1, 1])
                 index  value                test1  test2
0  2015-10-25 02:00:00     10  2015-10-25 02:00:00      0
2  2015-10-25 02:15:00     30  2015-10-25 02:15:00      0
4  2015-10-25 02:30:00     60  2015-10-25 02:30:00      0
6  2015-10-25 02:45:00     80  2015-10-25 02:45:00      0
1  2015-10-25 02:00:00     20  2015-10-25 02:00:00      1
3  2015-10-25 02:15:00     40  2015-10-25 02:15:00      1
5  2015-10-25 02:30:00     70  2015-10-25 02:30:00      1
7  2015-10-25 02:45:00     90  2015-10-25 02:45:00      1
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that will not deliver the desired output! That would only work if the dataframe would only consist of these 8 rows but there are 40000 rows. Your suggestion would mean that the quarters marked with a "1" would be sorted to the end and not to the right place

Comment: ok, could you create a good example of output then? I don't see definition of 'the right place' in your question